# How do the Docker Swarm Agents tell their IP to the Swarm Manager back?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'd like to understand the communication mechanism between the Docker Swarm Manager and the Docker Swarm Agents :

- The Swarm Manager generates a token.
- The Swarm Agents are generated, with this token passed to them. (and their own IP)

Now that the Manager needs to give instructions to the agents, how was it informed that the agents were existing to these IPs ?

Hypotesis :

Does the Agents register themselves on some docker.com server with their token, and the Manager gets their addresses from it using the same token ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Options are described in the doc here: 
  https://docs.docker.com/swarm/discovery/

In this example I use the **hosted discovery with Docker Hub**. There are other options like a ***static file***, ***consul***, ***etcd*** etc.

1. You create your docker cluster:

   `docker run -rm swarm create`

   This will give you a token to be used as your cluster id: `e4802398adc58493...longtoken`
2. You register one/multiple docker host(s) with your cluster

   `docker run -d swarm join --addr=172.17.42.10:2375 token://e4802398adc58493...longtoken`

   The ip address provided is the address of your docker host node.

   This is how the *future* manager will know about agents/nodes
3. You deploy the swarm manager to any of your docker host (let's say *172.17.42.10:2375*, the same one I used to create the swarm and register my first docker host)

   `docker run -d -p 9999:2375 swarm manager token://e4802398adc58493...longtoken`
4. To use the cluster you set the DOCKER_HOST to the ip address and port of your swarm manager

   `export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://172.17.42.10:2375"`

Using something like `docker info` should now return information about nodes in your cluster.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not what I asked, and sorry, but you're wrong :
- Point 2 : `docker run -d swarm join --addr=NODE_IP` , not the Swarm Manager's - Source : https://hub.docker.com/_/swarm/

Comment: In my example on point 2, i don't have yet a swarm manager. I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @Yow I edit my answer to make it clearer and to provide a better answer to your question